# React Navigation v5 with Tabs nested in Drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'd like drawer navigators to swipe in from the edges of a tab navigator. One drawer for the left tab and one drawer for the right tab. How can I use swipe gestures for both tab and drawer? I was able to do it in v4 using lock-closed and GestureRecognizer

Example:This is how I did it in v4:

```
const MainTabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Profile: { screen: Profile },
    Live: { screen: Live },
    Poll: { screen: Poll }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Live',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false,
      tabBarVisible: false
    }
  }
);

const ProfileDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Main: { screen: MainTabNavigator }
  },
  {
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
    drawerOpenRoute: 'ProfileMenuOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'ProfileMenuClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'ProfileMenuToggle',
    edgeWidth: 1000,
    contentComponent: props => (
      <ProfileMenu
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', opacity: 0.99 }}
        {...props}
      />
    )
  }
);

const PollDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    FirstDrawer: { screen: ProfileDrawer }
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {},
    // initialRouteName: 'FirstDrawer',
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    getCustomActionCreators: (route, stateKey) => ({
      openTopLevelDrawer: () => DrawerActions.openDrawer({ key: stateKey }),
      closeTopLevelDrawer: () => DrawerActions.closeDrawer({ key: stateKey })
    }),
    drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
    drawerOpenRoute: 'PollMenuOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'PollMenuClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'PollMenuToggle',
    edgeWidth: 1000,
    contentComponent: props => (
      <PollMenu
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', opacity: 0.99 }}
        {...props}
      />
    )
  }
);
```

Comment: I make a react navigation example view day ago: I don't know if this could help but you can check the code or download it if this is what you want to do : https://github.com/samuel3105/react-native-navigation

Comment: No unfortunately, I'm trying to retain the swipe functionality of the tab navigator